# Selecting the entire row instead of cell in the DataGrid in Compact Framework

Tags: select, datagrid, compact-framework, row, cell

How do I when the user clicks a cell in the DataGrid, the entire row is selected instead of just the cell is selected.

Answer (score 15):

Use following code on `datagrid1_CurrentCellChanged`

```
datagrid1.Select(this.datagrid1.CurrentRowIndex);
```

Comment: I was wondering if you could help with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491612/datagrid-programatically-unselect-a-cell). Thanks.