# Datagrid programmatically unselect a cell

Tags: winforms, compact-framework

I am using a PDA in which I have a `DataGrid` that has a list of `itemNames`, `barcode`, and `scanStatus`. The user scans a barcode and I search in my DataGrid for a match and I select the row for the item that is associated with the barcode. I set the scanStatus to `true`.

I was having a problem with the user touching the screen and the DataGrid's rows all got unselected.

So I tried to handle the DataGrid's `Click`, `DoubleClick`, and the `MouseUp` events. I loop through my grid where scanStatus is true and call `grid.Select(iteratorIndex)` else I call  `grid.UnSelect(iteratorIndex)`.

This re-selects the scanned item's rows. But the last cell that the user clicked also stays selected. How do I unselect that cell? I did search before posting and the only thing remotely matching my situation was [this thread](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/datagrid-cell-de-select-cell-t1360634.html), I tried the advice there but it but that did not answer my question.

Comment: I am trying to solve the exact same problem.  Did you find any solution?

Comment: @TheSean IIRC I Handle the above events selecting and unselecting as needed. At the end set `Grid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCell(-1,-1)`. I know setting CurrentCell to (0,0) did not work.

Comment: You can try unselecting all the rows if you don't know which one is selected:

    for (int i=0; i<((YourDataSourceTypeHere)grid.DataSource).Count; i++)
        grid.UnSelect(i);  

PS: The grid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCell(-1,-1) is throwing an {"Exception"} at my face :]